# phpexcel-generated xls file open as plain xml

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework, xls

I've been using PHPexcel in some part of my application and it works fine. In most cases the file created by phpexcel can be opened by libreoffice. But in one controller it generate a fine xls file. The file can be downloaded. But every time I open the file from libreoffice it shows text import. Then the file shows the actual xml file in the libreoffice calc. What could be the problem?

```
<?php
```

class ExcelXML_WorkBook
{

```
private $workSheets = array();

private $styles = array();
private $view = null;
private $fileName = '';
private $translateHeaders = false;
private $translateValueColumns = array();
private $hideHeaderData = false;
private $dataSetHeaderStyleId = null;
private $cellStyleMap = array();

  public function __construct($fileName = '', Zend_View_Interface $view = null,
    $translateHeaders = false, $translateValueColumns = array(), $hideHeaderData = false)
{
    // Initialise worksheet collection and add one worksheet
    $this->workSheets = array();
    $this->workSheets[] = new  ExcelXML_WorkSheet($this);
    $this->view = $view;
    $this->fileName = $fileName;
    $this->translateHeaders = $translateHeaders;
    $this->translateValueColumns = $translateValueColumns;
    $this->hideHeaderData = $hideHeaderData;
    $this->initWorkBookStyle();
}
 public function __get($name)
{
    return $this->$name;
}

  public function __set($name, $value)
{
    $this->$name = $value;
}
  public function __isset($name) {
    return isset($this->$name);
}
  private function initWorkBookStyle()
{
    // Default text with single solid black lines as inner and outer borders.
    $this->addStyleFromArray(array(
        'borders' => array(
            'allborders' => array(
                'style' =>  ExcelXML_Style_Border::STYLE_CONTINUOUS,
                'weight' => 1,
                'color' => '#000000',
            ),
        ),
    ));

    // White bold text on a red background with single solid black lines as inner and outer borders.
    $this->dataSetHeaderStyleId = $this->addStyleFromArray(array(
        'font' => array(
            'bold' => true,
            'color' => '#FFFFFF'
        ),
        'alignment' => array(
            'horizontal' =>  ExcelXML_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
            'vertical' =>  ExcelXML_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER
        ),
        'fill' => array(
            'type' =>  ExcelXML_Style_Interior::PATTERN_SOLID,
            'color' => '#FF0000'
        ),
        'borders' => array(
            'allborders' => array(
                'style' =>  ExcelXML_Style_Border::STYLE_CONTINUOUS,
                'weight' => 1,
                'color' => '#000000'
            ),
        ),
    ));

    $this->cellStyleMap['h_center'] = $this->addStyleFromArray(array(
        'alignment' => array(
            'vertical' =>  ExcelXML_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
            'horizontal' =>  ExcelXML_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER
        )
    ));

    $this->cellStyleMap['h_left'] = $this->addStyleFromArray(array(
        'alignment' => array(
            'vertical' =>  ExcelXML_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
            'horizontal' =>  ExcelXML_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT
        )
    ));

    $this->cellStyleMap['h_right'] = $this->addStyleFromArray(array(
        'alignment' => array(
            'vertical' =>  ExcelXML_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
            'horizontal' =>  ExcelXML_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT
        )
    ));

}
/**
 * Generate header xml of Workbook
 */
private function getHeader()
{
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
         <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
             xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
             xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
             xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">';
}

/**
 * Add Sheet to workbook
 * @param  ExcelXML_Worksheet $sheet
 */
public function addSheet($sheet)
{
    $this->workSheets[] = $sheet;
}

/**
 * Get Worksheet by name/title
 * @param string $name
 * @return  ExcelXML_Worksheet
 */
public function getSheetByName($name)
{
    $workSheet = null;
    $worksheetCount = count($this->workSheets);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $worksheetCount; $i++) {
        if ($this->workSheets[$i]->title == $name) {
            $workSheet = $this->workSheets[$i];
        }
    }

    return $workSheet;
}

/**
 * Get sheet by index
 *
 * @param int $sheetIndex Sheet index
 * @return  ExcelXML_Worksheet
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function getSheet($sheetIndex = 0)
{
    if (!isset($this->workSheets[$sheetIndex])) {
        throw new Exception("Sheet index is out of bounds.");
    }
    return $this->workSheets[$sheetIndex];
}

/**
 * Add style from array to Workbook
 * @param array $styleArray
 * @param boolean $isDefault
 * @param int $parentStyleId
 * @return int $styleId
 */
public function addStyleFromArray($styleArray = array(), $parentStyleId = null)
{
    $style = new  ExcelXML_Style();
    foreach ($styleArray as $styleName => $property) {
        switch ($styleName) {
            case  ExcelXML_Style::FONT:
                $bold = ($property['bold'] == true)? 1 : 0;
                $color = (!empty($property['color']))? $property['color'] : '';
                $fontName = (!empty($property['name']))? $property['name'] : '';
                $italic = (!empty($property['italic']))? 1 : 0;
                $style->setFont($bold, $color, $fontName, $italic);
                break;
            case  ExcelXML_Style::ALIGNMENT:
                $wraptext = !empty($property['wraptext'])? 1 : 0;
                $horizontal = !empty($property['horizontal'])? $property['horizontal'] : '';
                $vertical = !empty($property['vertical'])? $property['vertical'] : '';
                $style->setAlignment($wraptext, $horizontal, $vertical);
                break;
            case  ExcelXML_Style::INTERIOR:
                $color = (!empty($property['color']))? $property['color'] : '';
                $pattern = !empty($property['type'])? $property['type'] : 'solid';
                $style->setBackgroundColor($color, $pattern);
                break;
            case  ExcelXML_Style::BORDERS:
                if (!empty($property['allborders'])) {
                    $color = (!empty($property['allborders']['color']))? $property['allborders']['color'] : '';
                    $lineStyle = !empty($property['style'])? $property['style'] :  ExcelXML_Style_Border::STYLE_CONTINUOUS;
                    $weight = !empty($property['weight'])? $property['weight'] : 1;
                    $style->setBorder($color, $lineStyle, $weight);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    return $this->setStyle($style, $parentStyleId);
}

/**
 * Set style object to Workbook
 *
 * @param  ExcelXML_Style $style
 * @param string $parentStyleId
 * @return int
 */
private function setStyle( ExcelXML_Style $style, $parentStyleId = null)
{
    $this->styles[] = $style;
    $styleId = count($this->styles);
    $style->setId($styleId);
    $style->setParentStyleId($parentStyleId);
    return $styleId;
}

/**
 * Set Header Data containing extra information to respective worksheet
 * @param array $headerDataArray
 */
public function setHeaderData($headerDataArray)
{
    foreach ($headerDataArray as $sheetIndex => $headerData) {
        $sheet = $this->getSheet($sheetIndex);
        $sheet->headerData = $headerData;
    }
}

/**
 * Set Column format Style to respective worksheet
 * @param array $columnFormatArray
 */
public function setColumnFormatData($columnFormatArray)
{
    foreach ($columnFormatArray as $sheetIndex => $columnFormat) {
        $sheet = $this->getSheet($sheetIndex);
        $sheet->columnFormat = $columnFormat;
    }
}

/**
 * Set Cell Styling to respective worksheet
 * @param array $cellFormatArray
 */
public function setCellFormatData($cellFormatArray)
{
    $hashKey = '';
    foreach ($cellFormatArray as $sheetIndex => $cellFormatData) {
        foreach ($cellFormatData as $row => $cellFormatByColumn) {
            foreach ($cellFormatByColumn as $column => $cellFormat) {
                $formatArray = !is_array($cellFormat['font'])? array($cellFormat['font']) : $cellFormat['font'];
                $fontStyleArray = array(
                    'bold' => in_array( Report_Report::FONT_FORMAT_BOLD, $formatArray),
                    'italic' => in_array( Report_Report::FONT_FORMAT_ITALIC, $formatArray),
                    'underline' => in_array( Report_Report::FONT_FORMAT_UNDERLINE, $formatArray)?  ExcelXML_Style_Font::UNDERLINE_SINGLE :  ExcelXML_Style_Font::UNDERLINE_NONE
                );
                $hashKey = $fontStyleArray['bold'].'|'.$fontStyleArray['italic'].'|'.$fontStyleArray['underline'];

                if (!isset($this->cellStyleMap[$hashKey])) {
                    $sheet = $this->getSheet($sheetIndex);
                    $columnAlignStyle = null;
                    $parentId = null;
                    if (isset($sheet->columnFormat[$column]) && isset($sheet->columnFormat[$column]['align'])) {
                        $columnAlignStyle = $sheet->columnFormat[$column]['align'];
                        if (isset($this->cellStyleMap['h_'.$columnAlignStyle])) {
                            $parentId = $this->cellStyleMap['h_'.$columnAlignStyle];
                        }
                    }
                    $this->cellStyleMap[$hashKey] = $this->addStyleFromArray(
                        array('font' => $fontStyleArray),
                        $parentId
                    );
                }
                if (isset($this->cellStyleMap[$hashKey])) {
                    $cellFormatArray[$sheetIndex][$row][$column] = $this->cellStyleMap[$hashKey];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    foreach ($cellFormatArray as $sheetIndex => $cellFormat) {
        $sheet = $this->getSheet($sheetIndex);
        $sheet->cellFormat = $cellFormat;
    }
}

/**
 * Set Column title to respective worksheet
 * @param array $columnTitleArray
 */
public function setColumnTitleData($columnTitleArray)
{
    foreach ($columnTitleArray as $sheetIndex => $columnTitles) {
        $sheet = $this->getSheet($sheetIndex);
        $sheet->columnTitles = $columnTitles;
    }
}

/**
 * Set Column Type to respective Worksheet
 * @param array $columnTypeArray
 */
public function setColumnTypeData($columnTypeArray)
{
    foreach ($columnTypeArray as $sheetIndex => $columnTypes) {
        $sheet = $this->getSheet($sheetIndex);
        $sheet->columnTypes = $columnTypes;
    }
}

/**
 * Set custom Dataset header to respective worksheet
 * @param array $dataSetHeaderArray
 */
public function setDataSetHeader($dataSetHeaderArray)
{
    foreach ($dataSetHeaderArray as $sheetIndex => $dataSetHeader) {
        $sheet = $this->getSheet($sheetIndex);
        $sheet->dataSetHeader = $dataSetHeader;
    }
}

/**
 * Set Excel Dataset to respective Worksheet
 * there could be multiple dataset for one worksheet
 *
 * @param array $dataSetArray
 */
public function setDataSet($dataSetArray)
{
    foreach ($dataSetArray as $sheetIndex => $dataSet) {
        $sheet = $this->getSheet($sheetIndex);
        if ($dataSet instanceof  Report_MultiDataSet) {
            foreach ($dataSet->dataSetArray as $dataSet) {
                $sheet->setDataSetList($dataSet);
            }
        } else {
            $sheet->setDataSetList($dataSet);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Render WorkBook Style as XML
 */
private function renderStyleAsXml()
{
    if (count($this->styles) > 0) {
        $styleXml = '<ss:Styles>';
        foreach ($this->styles as $style) {
            $styleXml .= $style->asXml();
        }
        $styleXml .= '</ss:Styles>';
    }
    echo $styleXml;
}

/**
 * Get Footer of the workbook to end file
 */
private function getFooter()
{
    echo '</Workbook>';
}

/**
 * Set All necessary header to make file downloadable as excel xml
 */
private function outputExcelHeaders()
{
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression','Off');

    // set the headers
    header('Pragma: public');
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");                 // Date in the past
    header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');     // HTTP/1.1
    header('Cache-Control: pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0');    // HTTP/1.1
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: none');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;');                 // This should work for IE & Opera
    header("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");                     // This should work for the rest
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($this->fileName).'.xml"');
}

/**
 * Prepare Excel with provided data before
 */
private function prepareExcel()
{
    $this->getHeader();
    $this->renderStyleAsXml();
    foreach ($this->workSheets as $sheetIndex => $sheet) {
        $sheet->render();
    }
    $this->getFooter();
}

/**
 * Render ExcelXML file and give to download
 */
public function render()
{
    $this->outputExcelHeaders();
    $this->prepareExcel();
}

/**
 * Prepare and Save File to given path
 * @param string $path
 */
public function save($path)
{
    ob_start();
    $this->prepareExcel();
    file_put_contents($path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$this->fileName, ob_get_contents());
    ob_end_clean();
}

/**
 * Get Content of file to send as attachment in email
 * @return Zend_Mime_Part
 */
public function renderAsMimePart()
{
    ob_start();
    $this->prepareExcel();

    $mimePart = new Zend_Mime_Part(ob_get_contents());
    $mimePart->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
    $mimePart->type = 'application/x-msexcel';
    $mimePart->disposition = 'attachment';
    $mimePart->filename = $this->fileName.'.xml';

    ob_end_clean();
    return $mimePart;
}
```

}

?>

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks, I am using the above class... Not sure exactly is there any problem with function outputExcelHeaders and getHeader